# Why isn't the head node of my linked list being deleted?

Tags: java, linked-list

Okay, so i'm playing with linked list in Java. I'm trying to understand why my deleteNode method doesn't delete the head node. It works for other nodes.

Here's the method

```
Node deleteNode(Node head, int d){
        Node n = head;
        if(n.data == d){
            return head.next;
        }

        while(n.next != null){
            if(n.next.data == d){
                n.next = n.next.next;
                return head;
            }
            n = n.next;
        }
        return head;
    }
```

Sample input:

```
Node ll = new Node(1);
ll.appendToTail(2);
ll.appendToTail(3);
```

When I call my method

```
ll.deleteNode(ll, 2);
```

and then print the current Nodes, I get the correct output of 1->3, however when I use the method to delete the initial node or the head

```
ll.deleteNode(ll, 1);
```

I get the output 1->2->3, but I expect 2->3, where 2 becomes the new head. Below is the entire implementation just incase

```
public class Node {

    Node next = null;
    int data;

    public Node(int d){
        data = d;
    }

    void appendToTail(int d){

        Node end = new Node(d); //Item to append to the end
        Node n = this; //To access Class object next

        while(n.next != null){
            n = n.next;
        }
        n.next = end;
    }

    Node deleteNode(Node head, int d){
        Node n = head;
        if(n.data == d){
            return head.next;
        }

        while(n.next != null){
            if(n.next.data == d){
                n.next = n.next.next;
                return head;
            }
            n = n.next;
        }
        return head;
    }

    void printNodes(){ 
        Node n = this;
        while(n.next != null){
            System.out.println(n.data);
            n = n.next;     
        }
        System.out.println(n.data); //print out the last node
    }

    //For fun, to simulate how python print's a list
    // printed example [1, 2, 3]
    void listNodes(){
        Node n = this;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[");
        while(n.next != null){
            sb.append(n.data).append(", ");
            n = n.next;
        }
        sb.append(n.data);
        sb.append("]");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the function you wrote, you should use it like `ll = ll.deleteNode(ll, 1)`.

Besides, you do not need to take a `head` parameter, as `this` is already `head`.

If you want, you can also change the return type to `void`, replace the `return head.next` with `data = head.next.data; next = head.next.next`, and replace `return head;` with `return;` ; then you will be able to call it like you are trying to.

Here is the complete method:

```
void deleteNode(int d){
    Node n = this;
    if(n.data == d){
        data = next.data;
        next = next.next;
        return;
    }

    while(n.next != null){
        if(n.next.data == d){
            n.next = n.next.next;
            return;
        }
        n = n.next;
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `deleteNode()` to delete the head of the list, the method doesn't do anything.

This code executes:

```
    Node n = head;
    if(n.data == d){
        return head.next;
    }
```

It returns the `.next` field of the head node but doesn't modify anything -- so it can't be deleting anything.  When you call `deleteNode()` for anything other than the head you will reach the `while` loop and actually modify the list.

Comment: Oh..I thought that it would assign the the current head to the next object in the list.